# Exchange 2010 New database on a SAN - best practice

Tags: exchange-2010, storage-area-network, netapp

We currently have a single database (on it's own Netapp Volume and LUN) and a separate Volume and LUN for the transaction logs.

So, to map it out as the server sees it: 
C:\ Server Install
D:\ Database Disk
L:\ Log Disk

I need to create a new database, (as the current one is getting quite large,) and then move some mailboxes to the new database.

I'm fine with creating the database and moving the mailboxes. The part I am unclear on is WHERE I should create it.

Is it OK to create the new database on D:\ which is the same as the original mailbox or would this cause problems?

Can I point the transaction logs to L:\ and just use a different folder or would this cause problems?

For some background info, We have around only 100 exchange users and a single exchange server holding all the roles.

Sorry if the question is a bit basic but I am struggling to find any resources that deal specifically with 2010 and SAN configurations.

Comment: From a function point of view, placing the new database/logs in the existing locations will work.

Comment: Pure preference,  SAN so everything is shared anyway, your only possible benefit is queue depth on the LUN, I've always preferred least LUNs possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We organize our databases by storage group on a drive. So SG1 is on G: and SG2 is on I:. We have multiple databases per storage group and thus per drive.

We are running an all flash storage array so for us iops are not an issue.

To your actual question I would say it is more likely a prefrence. By placing them on diffrent drives you can provide diffrent levels of service if needed as well as doubling your iop potential if your using dedicated disks (raw mapping).

Logs apply the same. We create a diffrent vDisk for them for flexibility but if you have the performance it should work either way.